# FullCalendar Select Method

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am creating a interactive calendar using FullCalendar but I have run into a nice to have snag.

When the person makes the hour range selection (click and drag) I have a dialog open and allows the user to title their event and modify the date/time selection if needed.  What I would like is to re-render the selection with the new date/time selection from the dialog if it changes.

Currently when I run the select method my selection area is just removed from the view, I want it to stay and be updated to the current selection.

Here is my code

```
$('#UserCalendarToHour, #UserCalendarToMin').change(function(){
    var allDay = false;
    var startDate = new Date($('#UserCalendarFromDate').val()+' '+$('#UserCalendarFromHour').val()+':'+$('#UserCalendarFromMin').val());
    var endDate = new Date($('#UserCalendarToDate').val()+' '+$('#UserCalendarToHour').val()+':'+$('#UserCalendarToMin').val());
    if($('#UserCalendarAllDay').is(':checked')){
        allDay = true;
    }
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('select',startDate.toString(),endDate.toString(),allDay);
});
```

Now what am I missing.

Comment: So, `unselect` happens, but the `select` after doesn't, correct? Have you tried just firing the `select` without the `unselect`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select` method is expecting `startDate` and `endDate` as Date objects. You're converting them to text. Also, according to docs,

> allDay is a boolean indicating if entire days were selected (days in
>   month view or the "all-day" slot in the agenda view) or time slots
>   were selected.

So if you are selecting time slots you need to set it to `false`.

You'll see it more clearly in the select callback documentation. The same type for arguments seem to apply for the method. It took me a while to realize it. You may get confused with, for instance, the Event Object attributes, which have similar names but are of different type. See it here:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/selection/select_callback/